# Changing white-space on the beginning of a file name

Tags: batch-file, removing-whitespace

We have randomly named pdf documents being uploaded to a Google Drive folder. When uploading these documents sometimes there is a space in front of the file name, *ex. " 12345.pdf"*. I want to delete this whitespace in front of the file name with a batch file.

Comment: You tried [`LTrim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c623wz83(v=vs.84).aspx) it's a built in function?

Comment: I am surprised that you can have a file whose name begins with a space.

Comment: There could be a whole host of solutions, none of which are worth presenting as a response without us seeing the current script being used for the process! Please update your question using the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46587646/edit) to include that code and any specific related information, _otherwise your question is too broad and off topic here_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim leading spaces including tabs](//stackoverflow.com/q/1098606)

Comment: @Compo, either way, it would have been answered before this isn't exactly rocket science even for beginners.

Comment: To those inclined to close this question - I understand why. But you might think better of it, only because the [newly discovered answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46588380/1012053) is so shockingly simple and unexpected. I think this Q&A is important enough that it should be kept around.

Comment: I would look at the program that is creating the PDF's to find out why it is naming the files with a space at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of leading spaces is constant, then there is actually a simple one liner using nothing but REN that will remove the leading space(s)!

If you have exactly one leading space, then you can use

```
ren " *" "/*"
```

If two leading spaces, then

```
ren "  *" "//*"
```

and so on...

This behavior is described at https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090. But be careful. At one point I thought I saw that a single `/` could strip multiple leading characters if the leading characters were spaces. But I haven't been able to reproduce this behavior. Now all I get is the "expected" behavior that `/` strips exactly one leading character.

If the number of leading spaces varies, then you can use the following to safely remove all leading spaces (assuming there are no name collisions with the result).

```
for %A in (" *") do @for /f "tokens=*" %B in ("%A") do @ren "%A" "%B"
```

Don't forget to double the percents if you put the code in a batch script.

Comment: Hi sir, works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: @StephanRoodt - You might consider accepting the answer, by clicking on the checkmark near the upper left corner of the answer.

Comment: The solution has nothing to do with VBScript, so the question is misleading, unclear and likely shouldn't have been answered in the first place. But as it has, I've [edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46587646/4) to remove the unnecessary reference to VBScript.

Comment: Actually I cannot confirm the special behaviour that one `/` strips all leading spaces; on my Windows 7 machine, `/` removes one space only! Are you using Windows 10?

Comment: @aschipfl - Thanks. I'm no longer able to reproduce the multi space strip behavior on Win 7 or Win 10. Now I'm wondering if I ever saw it, or perhaps I fooled myself :-/ I'll do some more tests when I get time, and then I'll probably have to update this answer.

Comment: @aschipfl - I updated the answer.

Comment: Maybe it was quite late when you tested it back then... ;-) Anyway, I fixed your code as I am sure your actually meant `tokens=*`...

Comment: @aschipfl - Ugh - I guess I can't use the late excuse now. Thanks