# Remove leading spaces in Windows file names

Tags: batch-file

I have a Windows folder which contains a number of subfolders and files.  I have noticed that there are several hundred files whose names begin with a blank space, and thus will not copy to a cloud repository (OneDrive).  Is there a Windows command or batch file that I could run which would search a folder and its subfolders for any filenames which begin with a blank space, and remove that blank space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing white-space on the beginning of a file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587646/changing-white-space-on-the-beginning-of-a-file-name)

Comment: Not an awful question, +1, should be on super user. I found this useful

Answer (score 5):

A batch file way to do this is as follows:

```bat
@echo off
for /R %%A IN (" *") do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%B IN ("%%~nxA") do (
        ren "%%A" "%%B"
    )
)
```

- We loop through all subfolders with `/R` option.
- We want to find all files starting with a space, so we specify it in parenthesis (`(" *")`).

  - For each file found we loop through its name specifying `tokens=*` which means to remove any spaces in front.
  - So, after that we got:
    `%%A` `=` full path to file with a space in its start
    `%%B` `=` just the filename without spaces

    - So, we rename them with `ren` command.
  - `(closing parenthesis)`
- `(closing parenthesis)`

---

This can be also run from command line in one line:

```bat
for /R %A IN (" *") do @for /F "tokens=*" %B IN ("%~nxA") do @ren "%A" "%B"
```

Comment: There is a typo in batch file code. It should be "%%~nxA" instead of "%~nxA"

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following in PowerShell, update the path variable to point to your folder.

```
$path = # Path to folder
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse 
Foreach($file in $files)
{
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ($file.Name).Trim()
}
```